# How to generate 10 million random strings in bash

Tags: string, bash, random, generator

I need to make a big test file for a sorting algorithm. For that I need to generate 10 million random strings. How do I do that? I tried using cat on /dev/urandom but it keeps going for minutes and when I look in the file, there are only around 8 pages of strings. How do I generate 10 million strings in bash? Strings should be 10 characters long.

Comment: (1) `/dev/null`? How would that work at all? (2) bash isn't a good choice of tools for the job. I'd suggest using something else. (3) What kind of strings? What length? You certainly *could* take the base64-encoded input as `/dev/urandom` and then split it into chunks. What size chunk do you need? Does a single character count as a "string"? Details matter.

Comment: I wanted to write urandom, that's what I was using. Sorry.

Comment: Does a uniform length give the best test of your sorting code?  Do you really need variable length strings?  Or is this just a first stepping stone on the way?

Comment: All uniq? Format of strings? Numeric alone or hex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not guarantee uniquness, but gives you 10 million random lines in a file. Not too fast, but ran in under 30 sec on my machine:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 10000000 > file
```

Comment: Throwing away characters that aren't alphanumeric is pretty expensive -- you're using a lot more bytes from `/dev/urandom` than you need.

Comment: Charles Duffy is right, you can replace your first two commands with `base64 -w0 /dev/urandom`.  This completes on my machine in about 7 seconds.

Comment: And of course, the [cat is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) -- `tr` is pesky in that it doesn't accept a file name argument, but `tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' </dev/urandom` works around that nicely

Answer (score 7):

Using openssl:

```
#!/bin/bash

openssl rand -hex $(( 100000000 * 4 )) | \
while IFS= read -rn8 -d '' r; do
    echo "$r"
done
```

Comment: Fork off a new program *every single iteration*?! That's ridiculously slow, and utterly needless (when you could have just one invocation of `openssl rand` spit out all the bytes you need, and split it into strings after).

Comment: Thanks, Charles. I've updated my answer. Be nice if openssl had an option to suppress the trailing newline!

Comment: Much better indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Update, if you have `shuf` from *GNU coreutils* you can use:

```
shuf -i 1-10000000 > file
```

Takes 2 sec on my computer. (Thanks [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501917/how-to-generate-10-million-random-strings-in-bash/47501946?noredirect=1#comment81963038_47501946)!)

---

You can use `awk` to generate sequential numbers and shuffle them with `shuf`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<10000001;i++){print i}}' | shuf > big-file.txt
```

This takes ~ 5 sec on my computer

Comment: That's quite a lot slower than the same loop would be in `awk`, *especially* if we didn't care about duplicates (and so didn't need the expense of a `shuf`).

Comment: You say I should use `awk 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<n;i++){print i}}' ... `  instead of the bash loop?

Comment: If this is Gnu shuf, use the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 2):

If they don't need to be uniq, you can do:

```
$ awk -v n=10000000 'BEGIN{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%010d\n", int(rand()*n)}' >big_file
```

That runs in about 3 seconds on my iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Don't generate it, download it. For example *Nic funet fi* has file `100Mrnd` (size 104857600) in its `/dev` (just *funet* below). 10M rows, 10 bytes on each row is 100M but using `xxd` to convert from bin to hex (`\x12` -> `12`) we'll only need 50M bytes, so:

```
$ wget -S -O - ftp://funet/100Mrnd | head -c 50000000 | xxd -p | fold -w 10 > /dev/null
$ head -5 file
f961b3ef0e
dc0b5e3b80
513e7c37e1
36d2e4c7b0
0514e626e5
```

(replace *funet* with the domain name and path given and `/dev/null` with your desired filename.)