# Random String Inside of A JSON in Bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, random

I Want to insert A random String inside of a JSON in a Bash script I'm using to send _bulk od documents in the API of Elasticsearch:

```
SECONDS=0;
for i in {0..1000}
do
echo "Number: $i \n"

curl --location --request POST 'localhost:9000/_bulk' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"index": {"_index": "yotam-les", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "A975463f711"}}
{"Amount": "3", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "A975463f711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index": {"_index": "yotam-les", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "975463943"}}
{"Amount": "7", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}

'

done
echo "\n took " $SECONDS "seconds"
exit 0
```

For example, in this bash script, I want to do something like

"_id": "<RANDOMLY_GENERATED_STRING>"

where "_id": "A975463f711" this part is.
and of course, I wish that each iteration would randomly generate the ID itself.

in order to create a random string I know I can do this:

```
chars=abcd1234ABCD
echo -n "${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}"
```

but how do I Inject it inside the JSON?

to be more clear my problem is when I try to do this:

"_id": "${chars:RANDOM%${#chars}:1}"

because of the --data-raw '...' - it can only contain a raw string

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What specific part of that are you having trouble with? Do you need to know how to generate a random string? Or how to insert that string into a JSON document? Ask only one question at a time, after checking if it's already been asked before.

Comment: For example, how to generate a random strings in bash in bulk is given at [how to generate 10 million random strings in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501917/how-to-generate-10-million-random-strings-in-bash)

Comment: ...and [what linux command can add new filed key value pair to a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575500/what-linux-command-can-can-add-new-filed-key-value-pair-to-a-json-file) tells you how to insert new data into JSON.

Comment: So, a good place to start would be trying to combine the answers to those two questions, and then asking about a _specific problem_ you encounter with that implementation, should you encounter any problem at all.

Comment: Maybe reaching the point where bash is not the easiest nor the clearest. As example using php just like your example, would almost works straight away.

Comment: `new_json=$(jq --arg id "$random_string" '._id=$id' <<<"$old_json")`, to summarize. (Now that you've clarified that you know how to generate random strings and only want to know how to inject them into JSON there are lots of duplicates covering that; but having already voted to close as too-broad, I can't vote to close as duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

> but how do Inject it inside the JSON?

You are inside `'....` single quotes. So do:

1. End single quoting.
2. Open double quotes.
3. Inject it!
4. End double quotes.
5. Open single quotes.

```
var=$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM$RANDOM # ie. random string
curl .... \
--data-raw '{"index": {"_index": "yotam-les", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "'"$var"'"}}
#          ^                                                           ^^^^^^^^
{"Amount": "3", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "A975463f711", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
{"index": {"_index": "yotam-les", "_type": "_doc", "_id": "975463943"}}
{"Amount": "7", "Quantity": "2", "Id": "975463943", "Client_Store_sk": "1109"}
'
```

Comment: This is only sound if you know what characters your random string can contain, and none of them require quoting to be valid inside JSON.

Comment: this is helpful but, the problem is that each iteration, I would have the same random string that was created outside rather than just a random var that was generated inside my scope. but I still can use it, whilst taking the "i" iterator thanks!